# install sails manually on ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sails.js, ubuntu-14.04

My Ubuntu server is behind firewall.hence when ever I try to run command to install sails via putty  using command    npm install sails -g ,I get error   Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.
There fore I though if I can download the sails package on to my local and then moving the package manually on firewall server and installing it. I tried looking for some help on web but could not get. Please guide how to proceed

Comment: you'd also need the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

If your computer is not connected to the internet npm will not work.

If you have another computer connected to the internet, you can run the npm commands there and afterwards copy the contents to the other computer. (e.g. via USB stick)

In most cases you should have no problems, even on different operating systems.

***Note on global modules***: For global modules (e.g. gulp, bower, forever) you will not be able to install into node_modules using this technique. However, you can install them locally by saving them to your package json and running them from their local path.

e.g.

```
npm install --save forever
./node_modules/forever/bin/forever
```

Check the files system for the exact path.

Comment: @AdrianLynch : oops. Meant to say OS. corrected now thanks

Comment: I've done exactly this when sat on a train with no internet connection. When ya needs a module, go take it! :D

Comment: I tried the above option.
I moved the folders from /usr/lib/node_modules from local to server behind firewall at location /usr/lib/node_modules.
After which i tried to run command "forever start app.js" , i get an error message "forever: command not found"
please guide if i need to move some other files and folder.

Comment: @kab: did my updated note about global modules help you?

Comment: Yes it did helped me a little but i have planned to use docker.Thanks for your guidance and responses.